# Dataset for sports actions

Tags: data-request, sports

I have a deep learning task where I have to recognize sports actions related to a specific sport (e.g. football, football, basketball, volleyball) using the [YOLO algorithm](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-to-implementing-the-yolo-algorithm-for-multi-object-detection-in-images-99cf240539). What can be a good dataset? At the moment I have tried with UFC but with poor results

Comment: it's not really clear if you are looking for video, or tagged/labeled actions.

Comment: I need images( or video) with labeled actions and boundaries box

Answer (score 1):

The Sports Videos in the Wild (SVW) dataset is a computer vision dataset with videos tagged by sport and bounding boxes for actions: http://cvlab.cse.msu.edu/project-svw.html